# JavaFX: why KeyEvent isn't returning data outside method

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, javafx-8, keycode

I am relatively new to programming and I'm struggling. I would greatly, GREATLY appreciate your assistance. I'm trying to make a simple program where the user can change the Y Coordinate of a dot displayed on a transparent stage with the Number 1 & 2 Keys on their keyboard, to move it up and down. The problem is the Y Value Variable I made outside the methods will not update when the keys are pressed. I know the actual method itself works, because I ran a print line test... I just can't get the value to update anywhere else but that method. Any advice?

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

        //Program where the user can adjust the Y Coordinate of a dot by 
                     pressing 1 & 2 Keyboard Keys 

public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<KeyEvent>  {


    double x = 680; //The X Value of Dot (Never Changes)
    double y = 380; //The Y Value of Dot (The value users can change)

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {                                        

                    //Root Properties
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(); 
        root.getChildren().addAll(dot(), display());            
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: null;");    

                    //Scene Properties

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1369, 715);         
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(this);
        scene.setFill(null);    

                    //Stage Settings
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);           
        stage.setScene(scene);                          
        stage.show();
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    }

    @Override
    //KeyEvent That Adjusts the Y Coordinate that Starts off at 380
    public void handle (KeyEvent event){

            KeyCode key = event.getCode();

            if (key == KeyCode.DIGIT1){y = y + 100;}
            if (key == KeyCode.DIGIT2){y = y - 100;}
            System.out.println(y); 
            //A test to see if the method actually works (it does)
            };


                    //Properties of the Dot
     public Text dot(){
         Text dot = new Text();
            dot.setText(".");
            dot.setFont(new Font (100));                
            dot.setFill(Color.RED);                 
            dot.setX(x);
            dot.setY(y);
            return dot;}

                    //Displays the Value of Y on the Screen
     public Text display(){
         Text display = new Text(Double.toString(y));
         display.setX(600);
         display.setY(300);

        return display;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

}
```

Comment: You don't have any code that, e.g. updates the text of `display` after the value of `y` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `dot` as a class *field* in addition to its `x, y` coordinates. Then you'll be able to access it from `handle()` method and change its position:

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

    Text dot;

    double x = 680; //The X Value of Dot (Never Changes)
    double y = 380; //The Y Value of Dot (The value users can change)

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        //Root Properties
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        dot = dot();
        root.getChildren().addAll(dot, display());
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: null;");

        //Scene Properties

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1369, 715);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(this);
        scene.setFill(null);

        //Stage Settings
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    }

    @Override
    //KeyEvent That Adjusts the Y Coordinate that Starts off at 380
    public void handle (KeyEvent event){

        KeyCode key = event.getCode();

        if (key == KeyCode.DIGIT1){dot.setY(dot.getY() + 100);}
        if (key == KeyCode.DIGIT2){dot.setY(dot.getY() - 100);}
        System.out.println(y);
        //A test to see if the method actually works (it does)
    };


    //Properties of the Dot
    public Text dot(){
        Text dot = new Text();
        dot.setText(".");
        dot.setFont(new Font(100));
        dot.setFill(Color.RED);
        dot.setX(x);
        dot.setY(y);
        return dot;}

    //Displays the Value of Y on the Screen
    public Text display(){
        Text display = new Text(Double.toString(y));
        display.setX(600);
        display.setY(300);

        return display;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

}
```

Comment: Or, better still, make `y` a `DoubleProperty` and then use bindings: `dot.yProperty().bind(y);` and `display.textProperty().bind(y.asString());`. Then you just do `y.set(y.get() + 100);` in the handler.